# NSNetService NSNetServiceListenForConnections use and checking for availability?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsnetservice

I'm creating an application that uses NSNetService to publish a server, and I've come across the `NSNetServiceListenForConnections` option that can be used in OS X 10.9 with the `publishWithOptions:` method. This new options is highlighted in the "[What's New in OS X 10.9](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_9.html)" page provided by Apple. It states `If you send the NSNetServiceListenForConnections option flag in the options value passed to publishWithOptions:, OS X automatically handles all of the connection management for you`, however, I don't see how this a new behavior? I currently just call the `publish` method and wait for the `ServerAcceptCallBack`, which is set by the `CFSocketCreate` method. I doesn't seem to make this any easier?

I'm following [some of Apple's code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaEcho/Listings/Server_EchoServer_m.html) from the CocoaEcho example, which gets a port and opens a `CFSocket`. I know you can pass `0` as the `port` parameter for the `initWithDomain: name: port:` method, but that chooses a "random" port, and I'm guessing that that's not a 100% safe thing to do. I thought that `NSNetServiceListenForConnections` might have something to do with that, but going by the description, it doesn't.

So to my actual question, after all the rambling:

What does the `NSNetServiceListenForConnections` option actually *do*, and (why) should I use it?

Side question: If I should use it, how do I check for availability? I've been told to use `if (&NSNetServiceListenForConnections != NULL)`, but `NSNetServiceListenForConnections` is an `NSUInteger` so I can't get the address (via `&`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this option, you don't have to open or manage the sockets at all (i.e. no calling CFSocketCreate). It creates the socket for you. Although I'm finding in 10.9.2 it isn't closing the socket properly if you call stop on the netService, but I'm still investigating. (It did seem to be closing them in 10.9.0 and 10.9.1). The socket seems to stay open until you quit the app.